# django forms don't show clear image button

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form modalform. There is an image field in it. The issue is that when the user clicks on the clear image, the image is removed from the models, but when the html file tries to retrieve the image, an error message appears `The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.`

So I'm planning to remove the clear button from django forms or is there any other best practises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% if obj.image %}
     <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}">
{% else %}
     your html content which you want to display after removing picture.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but think like this, I got dozens of HTML pages with images and I need to give this condition for each right, so how will you handle that?

Comment: ofc this block will be inside iteration whenever obj contains image it will have its url. and image is cleared means the else part will get rendered.  Or maybe you can use default picture concept. whenever you remove picture,   assign default picture to that obj and then you dont have to worry about html.

Comment: I've already given the default in models, but it only assigns that image while creating the data and not giving image, it won't add the default image if cleared

Comment: yes you have to add logic after removing the picture,  default.png will be assigned to that obj.